# Disable a button for a period of time

Tags: java, android, button, sms

I have written the following code to send an SMS message to a person...

```
Button but = (Button) a;
but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String messageToSend = "message";
        LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter = HomeActivity.loginDataBaseAdapter;
        car = ((EditText) b ).getText().toString();

        String phoneNum=loginDataBaseAdapter.getNum(car);
        if(phoneNum !="not") {
            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, messageToSend, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "MESSAGE SUCCESSFULLY SENT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "No Car Number found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

When the message is sent, I want to prevent the user from sending another SMS to the same user for a short period of time, such as disabling the `but` button. Could anyone please help me understand how I can disable the button for a period of time.

Comment: Disable the button as soon as the message was sent and start an alarm for the specific time after which it should be enabled. In the alarm code add code to enable the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way how to achieve this:

```
 ArrayList<String> sentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

When the button is clicked, you add the number or name to `ArrayList` with method

```
sentList.add("Number");
```

and when button clicked again you check:

```
for (String string : sentList){
    if (!string.equalsIgnoreCase(numberToCheck)) {
        //is new number - perform the action
    }
}
```

Hope this is what are you looking for.

**Edit**

```
ArrayList<String> sentNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
Button but = (Button) a;
but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
         String messageToSend = "message";
         LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter = HomeActivity.loginDataBaseAdapter;
        car = ((EditText) b ).getText().toString();
        String phoneNum = loginDataBaseAdapter.getNum(car);
        if(!sentNumbers.isEmpty(){
            for (String string : sentList){
                if (!string.equalsIgnoreCase(phoneNum)) {
                    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, messageToSend, null, null);
                    sentNumbers.add(phoneNum);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "MESSAGE SUCCESSFULLY SENT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "No Car Number found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }else{
            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, messageToSend, null, null);
            sentNumbers.add(phoneNum);
        }
    }
});
```

For clearing list of used numbers call (I guess some event must happens?):

```
sentList.clear();
```

Comment: can you please add your code to mine and the show it to me cause i'm the to android and unfortunately i have difficult in coding @Yurets

Comment: Okay. I'll do that, wait a little.

Comment: @JadDaoud, I cannot edit your question, so I edited my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

you can cancel the listener of button when to send request to server, and then you can set listener for the button when you get server callback.

```
sendRequest(params, ServerCallback(String arg) {

  public void onSuccess() {
    btn.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    //do something...
  }

  public void onFailed() {
    btn.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    //do something...
  }

});
btn.setOnClickListener(null);
```